# How do both these pieces of code have the same output, provided len>0

Tags: c++

I understand the second piece of code, but not the first one.

First code:

```
int max(int a[], int len)
{
 if (len == 1)
  return a[0];
 int m = max(a+1, len-1);
 if (a[0] > m)
  return a[0];
 return m;
}
```

Second code:

```
int max(int a[], int len) {
 int m = a[0];
 for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
  if (a[i] > m)
   m = a[i];
 return m;
}
```

In the first piece of code, what value is m actually storing everytime the function max is called

Comment: is `a+1` correct? `a` is an array not a number ..

Comment: @mad.meesh `a+1 == &a[1]`

Comment: @mad.meesh Remember, arrays decay to pointers in contexts like this, so this is pointer arithmetic.

Comment: ah ok i don’t write c++ so i learned something new today thanks

Answer (score 1):

`a+1` is the address of `a[1]`, so the recursive call returns the maximum of the sub-array starting with the second element, and assigns that to `m`. If the first element is larger than that, it's the largest element of the array, otherwise the largest element is `m`.

Suppose your array is `[1, 3, 6, 4, 2]` and `len = 5`. The first time `max()` is called, it does:

```
m = max([3, 6, 4, 2], 4);
```

This then does:

```
m = max([6, 4, 2], 3);
```

This does:

```
m = max([4, 2], 2);
```

which does:

```
m = max([2], 1);
```

This last case makes the test `if (len == 1)` true, so it returns `a[0]`, and the last `m` is set to `2`. It then does:

```
if (a[0] > m) {
    return a[0];
}
```

In that case, `a[0] == 4`, so this condition is successful and it returns `4` to the next `m`. In that caller, `a[0] == 6`, so the condition is again successful, so it returns `6` to its `m`.

In the next caller, `a[0] == 3`, so `a[0] > m` will be false, so it returns `m`, which is still `6`.

And in the next caller, `a[0] == 1`, so `a[0] > m` will still be false, so it returns `m`, which is still `6`, and that's the final result.

Comment: but how would the first program know which number is the largest, since the program hasnt actually found the largest number. also, what gets stored in m after each time the function is called if my array a is for eg [1,3,6,4,2] and len is 5

Comment: @AnubhavSaini You can use a debugger and follow the code to see how it works for yourself, that will be more illustrative than someone trying to explain that to you.

Comment: Even better, IMHO, is to pretend you're the computer. Write the values of the variables on a piece of paper, and execute the code by hand. You get a real feel for how things work this way.

Answer (score 0):

The first uses recursion, it keeps calling max with the trailing portion of the array until it is down to just one element, it then compares the first element of each preceding portion to the maximum element found so far.

Imagine you have the array {1, 2, 5, 4, 10, -1 };

The first max() starts by calling itself again with the array now pointing at the second element and len of 5, this continues until len is 1 and the array holds -1. It returns -1 and then compares that 10with 1 that call returns the 10 and so on until the outermost call returns 10.

Comment: should the program not end after it returns -1. (doesnt return essentially end the function?)

Comment: @AnubhavSaini There are multiple calls involved. That only ends the last call, all the other calls are still in progress, waiting for their recursive calls to return.